# Check for text file update results in printing output twice

Tags: python

I have a constantly updating text file `foo.txt`. I want to read the last line of `foo.txt` only if the file updates. I have a while loop constantly opening the file and checking it. Inside the loop, I have some code that prints the last line of the file, then stores it in `lastmsg.txt`. On the next iteration, it checks that the last line of the file is not equal to whatever is stored in `lastmsg.txt`. If the two values are not equal (the file has updated and a new line has been added), it will print the last message in the file. Here is the code

```
import time
while True:
    fileHandle = open ("foo.txt","r" )
    lineList = fileHandle.readlines()
    fileHandle.close()
    msg = lineList[len(lineList)-1]
    if(open("lastmsg.txt", "r").read() != msg):
        f = open("lastmsg.txt", "w")
        f.write(msg)
        print(msg)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

This seems to work, however, it prints `msg` twice. So if `abc` is amended to the file, the output will be

```
abc
abc
```

Comment: What you are doing there is quite problematic. You open your lastmsg.txt for reading. Then you never actually close it, and possibly open it again for writing, or open it again for reading in the next iteration. Try fixing this.

Comment: Best thing to do: Use a context manager for opening files (with open(...) as f: value = read(f))

Comment: why do you need to store it in a file? why not just store it in variable ?

Comment: Also there are probably better ways than reading the entire contents of foo.txt every half a second to check if the last line is new

Comment: If polling is good enough for you, I'd just watch if the "modified time" file stat changes. To read it:

`os.stat(filename).st_mtime`, if it has been changed, print last line

Answer (score 1):

I added f.close() line and after that, it prints msg just once.

```
import time
while True:
    fileHandle = open ("foo.txt","r" )
    lineList = fileHandle.readlines()
    fileHandle.close()
    msg = lineList[-1]
    if(open("lastmsg.txt", "r").read() != msg):
        f = open("lastmsg.txt", "w")
        f.write(msg)
        f.close()  # <---- new line
        print(msg)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below solution does make an assumption that you were only writing to the last line file as a buffer to know if you read the line before. Instead this solution just opens the file and reads to the end. Then will print any new lines that are written to the file after we read to the end.

When the file is updated the next call to `readline()` will retrieve the next line. this saves you reading the entire file every time.

```
import time
with open('query4.txt') as myfile:
    #run to the end of the file we are discarding these as 
    #only want to tail the last line of the file when its updated
    myfile.readlines()
    while True:
        line = myfile.readline()
        if line:
            print(line, end='')
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: of course you can just remove the time.sleep and just run infinitely and as soon as the file is updated the `readline()` will pick it up and print it